Python Intrinio Rest API calls
I'm running
Windows 11 Version 22H2 64-bit              OS Build 22621.3737             
                                
Python Version  Python 3.9.13               pip  --version  pip 24.0

            
                            

When I run:  pip install intrinio, I get:
Requirement already satisfied: intrinio in ...python311\lib\site-packages (0.2.1)                               
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.14 in ...python311\lib\site-packages (from intrinio) (2.0.1)                               
Requirement already satisfied …     

                    
                            

When I run:  pip install intrinio_sdk, I get:
Requirement already satisfied: intrinio_sdk in ...python311\lib\site-packages (6.27.3)                              
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3>=1.15 in ...python311\lib\site-packages (from intrinio_sdk) (1.26.12)                                
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10 in ...python311\lib\site-packages (from intrinio_sdk) (1.16.0)                             
Requirement already satisfied … 

                        

I'm trying to run this code in a .py:
import intrinio_sdk as intrinio
from intrinio_sdk.rest import ApiException

and I get this error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'intrinio_sdk'"
Like the module is not installed. How do I get Intrinio to run in python?
